# Energy decomposition analysis. Are there schemes that actually splits up the steric term?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, computational-chemistry

In quantum chemistry, there are many types of energy decomposition analysis (EDA) which partitions the interaction energy between two or more fragments into steric, polarisation, exchange and orbital energy terms

For example, in a Morukuma type decomposition method employed by ADF, the interaction energy is partitioned into electrostatic, pauli and orbital energy, which the last term can be further decomposed by Natural Orbitals for Chemical Valence (ETS-NOCV) to show the $\sigma,\pi,\delta$ contributions

In ALMO-EDA in Qchem, the energy is instead decomposed into electrostatic, pauli, dispersion and polarisation by using fragment electrical response functions (FERF) as an ortogonalisation scheme

Both methods were generalised to be applicable to multiple fragments in some more recent parts of the literature since 2014

Despite extensive work and examples on decomposing the electronic term, be it polarisation, orbital interactions or similar, it seems there isn't an example where the steric term is decomposed into contributions for each fragment. For example, considering a trimer of molecules, all such EDA schemes always report the steric or pauli repulsion term as the sum of contribution of all fragments, thus there is no information on how much sterics each fragment contributed in the complex.

Attempt to recover individual steric contributions of each fragment using the intuition that pauli repulsion in most EDA schemes are computed based on how much molecular volume is excluded in the overlapping region of the fragments and assuming that those depletion regions are additive, found that compared to the full 3 fragment EDA, the sum of steric terms for the pairwise fragments is off from the total steric by around 100-400 kJmol-1, suggesting there are higher order interactions not accounted for such as two fragments depends on the third one at the same time.

Is there a reason why it is not meaningful to decompose the steric or pauli term into fragment contributions?